# creating a new array of objects by rank

Tags: javascript, json

trying to create a new object based off of a json response.

say I've got a json response of

```
[{
    "id": "something1", 
    "diff": "0.09"
},     
{
    "id": "something2", 
    "diff": "0.7"
},     
{
    "id": "something3", 
    "diff": "0.1"
}]
```

how can I create a new array of objects while ranking each one by their diff to something like this?

```
[{
    "rank": 1,
    "id": "something2", 
    "diff": "0.7"
},     
{
    "rank": 2,
    "id": "something3", 
    "diff": "0.1"
},     
{
    "rank": 3,
    "id": "something1", 
    "diff": "0.09"
}]
```

Just need an idea of how the logic would work

```
var obj = [];
$.each(data, function(a) {
    // var rank = 0; 
    // logic - if/else based on diff     
    obj.push({"rank": rank, "id": this.id, "diff" : this.percent_change_1h })
});
```

Comment: how is diff =0.1 > 0.7 but 0.7 > 0.09

Comment: woops. fixed it

Comment: @totalnoob: Requesting an upvote/question answered if any of the solutions below worked for you. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```js
const data = [{
    id: "something1",
    diff: "0.09"
}, {
    id: "something2",
    diff: "0.7"
}, {
    id: "something3",
    diff: "0.1"
}, {
    id: "something4",
    diff: null
}];

const result = data
    .filter(({diff}) => diff !== null) // remove all objects with null for diff
    .sort((x, y) => y.diff - x.diff) // sort the data in descending order
    .map((x, i) => Object.assign({rank: i + 1}, x)); // copy object with rank

console.log("result:", result);
console.log("data:", data); // unchanged
```

This works for negative numbers too.

Comment: this is more elegant than the other answers. how do I remove any object that has null for diff?

Comment: I updated my answer showing how to remove all objects with `null` for `diff`.

Comment: great. just need the order reversed and I'll select this as the answer. it should be 0.1 > 0.7 > 0.09 > null

Comment: You mean that you want to sort it in ascending order?

Comment: You do realize that `0.1` is lesser than `0.7` right?

Comment: yea, ascending order

Comment: 0.7 > 0.1 > 0.09 > null

Comment: That's descending order. It's already in that order. However, `null` has been removed. Do you want to keep `null`?

Comment: ahh, was looking at data rather than result lol. you've got it perfect. thanks!

Comment: Just realized that if you use `filter` then you don't need to use `slice`. That makes things even cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a copy of the array with `slice` and then `sort` it by subtracting the diffs, and map it back with a `rank` property

```js
var arr = [{
  "id": "something1",
  "diff": "0.09"
}, {
  "id": "something2",
  "diff": "0.7"
}, {
  "id": "something3",
  "diff": "0.1"
}];

var arr2 = arr.slice().sort((a,b) => b.diff - a.diff).map((x,i) => (x.rank=(i+1),x));

console.log(arr2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important; top:0;}
```

Comment: your output has 0.09 > 0.1

Answer (score 1):

```js
var response = [{
    "id": "something1", 
    "diff": "0.09"
},     
{
    "id": "something2", 
    "diff": "0.7"
},     
{
    "id": "something3", 
    "diff": "0.1"
}]

var sorted = response.slice().sort(function(a, b) {    
    return (parseFloat(b.diff)) - (parseFloat(a.diff));
})
sorted.forEach(function(row, index) {
  row.rank = index +1;
});
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: You don't want to use `parseInt`. Try `parseFloat` instead.

Comment: Note that I edited your answer because the OP wants a "new array of objects".

Comment: thanks! can you explain to me how return (parseFloat(b.diff)) - (parseFloat(a.diff)); works while sorting?

Comment: you actually compare the values in the array by finding their difference, parseFloat is use to convert from string, mark if it helped

Comment: I think this solution changes the `response` array with rank attributes for each element. If @AaditMShah is right about that not changing it, then we need a mechanism to deep clone that array. Updated my answer below with JSON.parse based cloning. (may not be ideal ... )

Comment: thanks Sajeetharan. just noticed one thing, sometimes the json response includes negative values like -0.5. how to handle that?

Comment: @82Tuskers Good point. Never thought of that. The best way to do that IMHO would be to use `Object.assign`.

Comment: Nice ! I see. Never knew (or known) what is the best way to clone an object. For deep cloning there seems to be a warning listed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @totalnoob It does not matter, the above method should work

Comment: @Sajeetharan are you saying that adding a new key to the response array does not matter ?

Comment: @82Tuskers No, actually i was refering to his previous question

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
var response = [{
        "id": "something1",
        "diff": "0.09"
    },
    {
        "id": "something2",
        "diff": "0.7"
    },
    {
        "id": "something3",
        "diff": "0.1"
    }
];

var sorted = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));

sorted.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (Number(b.diff) - Number(a.diff)) > 0;
}).forEach(function(e, index) {
    e.rank = index + 1;
});

console.log(sorted);
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: What about the rank?

Comment: oops ! missed out on rank in the question. Fixed it.

Comment: You also missed that the OP wants a new array of objects. Hence, you should `slice` the array before sorting it.

Comment: right on ! The only thing is that you are probably looking for `splice`. Updated code.

Comment: No, you need to use `slice` because `splice(0)` removes all the elements from the original array. The original array should remain intact.

Comment: nice! one more thing to add, how do I handle negative values like -0.5?

Comment: It does. sorry. I meant null values

Comment: where do you want to rank them ? towards to top or the bottom ?

Comment: I want them at the bottom or removed